# PHP Parsing Email Message into Variables

Tags: php

I am currently working on building a system for my client that could be classed as a type of ticket system. However, instead of users inputting tickets like a normal system, the tickets are received from a third party (always the same third party) in email format that will be piped in.

What I need to look at (which I've thought using various ways but cant seem to pick out the best) is taking the details from the email and putting them into individual variables.

An example of the email that will be recieved is:

> Name: Harry Smith
>   Status:  Married
>   Address: 14 Tyne Road,
>   Littlewood
>   Manchester
>   MC2 3DN
>   Telephone: 01551 221502

Obviously the full email is alot longer, however what I am looking at doing is putting out the details from the email so I can process them as required by the new system. In reality I am looking for something that can store the information in the style of:

> Name: %name%
>   Status:  %status%
>   Address: %address%
>   Telephone: %telephone%

I just haven't quite worked out how to code a string search that will find `Name:` and store every after it up until `Status:` is reached.

Any help or pointers would be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the data file in line by line. Explode each line with a ":". If a count of that == 2 then you know you are on a new token, and in which case the key = index[0] and the value = index[1]. Now check the next line, if there is only one element after you run explode, simply add it to the previous key.

```
     $email = ...;//email here
     $email = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n\r","\n","\r"), "\r", $email); //fix line breaks         

     $emaillines = explode("\r", $email);
     $result = array();
     $key = "first"; 
     foreach($emaillines as $line)
     {
        $parts = explode(":",$line,2);
        if(count($parts)>1) 
        {
            $key = $parts[0];
            $result[$key] = $parts[1];
        }
        else
          $result[$key] .= "\r".$parts[0];
     }

     print_r($result);
```

Comment: Sounds promising, could you expand on that a bit more please, i.e. for the address that is on multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks will try this along with Salman's answer too. I'll come back with an update later on today.

Comment: Nicely done! Don't forget to initialize `$result = array();` before entering the for-each loop.

Comment: That works great, however I've got an error `Notice: Undefined index: in` which is on this line `$result[$key] .= "\r".$parts[0];`

Comment: and also, is there any way to discard details such as headings (which don't include a :). At the moment they are included in the array value that is above it

Comment: @Salman A. Thanks mate. @lethalMango Can you post the entire example email string? The undefined index would likely only occur if the first line doesn't have a title (so either there is no ":" or the part before the ":" is empty). Either way I think the best way to handle that is to clean them up a bit. pastebin.com -> paste in a few examples so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic string manipulation and regular expressions to extract data from the email message. Following code can serve as a starting point. The regular expression has lots of room for improvement.

```
<?php
$message = "Name: Harry Smith
Status: Married
Address: 14 Tyne Road,
Littlewood
Manchester
MC2 3DN
Telephone: 01551 221502";
preg_match(
    "@" .
    "^Name:(.*)" .
    "^Status:(.*)" .
    "^Address:(.*)" .
    "^Telephone:(.*)" .
    "@ms",
    $message,
    $match
);
var_dump($match);
// $match[1]...[4] contain the desired information
// you may want to trim() each value
?>
```

Comment: Its not actually 4 rows, it's something like 35, but yes each email that is received is one of two different layouts (identifiable by the email subject)

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace.

```
$string = str_replace("%name%", $name, $string);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at trying to store what %name% would be rather than replacing %name% with a value I already have